# Conversion Issue - Price in varchar fields to Decimal in MySql

Tags: mysql, sorting, varchar

I have a table `products` and field for price is `product_price` which is in `VARCHAR`.
I am getting price value from different sources which is in different formats like

```
52,20 
1,607,211
36,000
125.00
```

I do not want to ALTER my table like

```
ALTER TABLE products MODIFY COLUMN product_price DOUBLE;
```

The issue is i want to sort record But it do not working

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY CAST(product_price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) asc
```

How to sort it which will work for all type & formats of price?

Comment: ORDER BY REPLACE(price,',','')+0 ??

Comment: the problem is when the comma is used as decimal point as it seems to be the case for the example 56,20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to eliminate all the commas from you price string and then you can use query like below but its better if you use proper data type to store price so you don't need these types of hack in query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
ORDER BY replace(product_price,',','') * 1
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc8fa/1)

Comment: Looking at the examples it seems that some of the entries use ',' as decimal point (56,20) if that's the case then this will interpret 56,20 as 5620 instead of 56.20

Comment: @Jayvee i guess `,` does not denotes to decimal point its for money format like for 1000 it can be represented as 1,000 as money format or you can say number format